# What character can be prepended to the front a file or folder name to move it to the bottom?

Tags: file-management, filenames, cross-platform

If we stick an `!` character to the front of a directory name, it will be at the top of other directories when sorted.

Is there a character which has the opposite effect? Logically, a tilde (`~`) should do the trick, since it's at the end of the ASCII table. However, it's treated like an `!` by certain file managers. Attaching a lowercase `z` or numbering the folders is ruled out.

Answer (score 2):

For Windows Explorer at least, all special characters are sorted before normal characters. You could try using a different alphabet letters, such as Roman, Russian or Chinese characters. I'm not sure if it will translate cross platform.

Comment: Accented Z's, such as ASCII 142, sort after ordinary Z. You can test this by prefixing Alt+0142 to a filename. You might write a short program to create files with all Unicode first characters to check the sort order.  BTW, Windows has switches for sort order, such as turning on/off upper case before lower, so it is not guaranteed to always sort as you want.